# How to identify two rows with same characters at first stream

Tags: sas, indicator

I want to create a indicator variable, "same_first_two_nearby". That indicates that the first two characters of observations are equal to the nearby observations. I try to use the "duplication method", but I fail. Because the method can only "delete" the duplication but not keep.

```
PROC SORT data=temp NODUPKEY;
 BY customer_IN;
RUN;
```

The example of my data is as following.

```
data temp;
input  customer_IN $ 1-8 ;
cards;
ADJOHN. 
ADMARY.  
ADjerry.  
BWABBY.   
CFLUCY.   
CFLINDA.   
EFLAGNA.  
KTPAKAO.   
KTWANDA.    
;
run;
proc print data=temp;run;
```

I want to generate the results as the following.

```
customer_IN  same_first_two_nearby
    ADJOHN.                      1
    ADMARY.                      1 
    ADjerry.                     1 
    BWABBY.                      0 
    CFLUCY.                      1 
    CFLINDA.                     1 
    EFLAGNA.                     0 
    KTPAKAO.                     1 
    KTWANDA.                     1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to check only the observation next to the current observation. or you want to check all the observation for the similarity in the first 2 letter

Comment: I want to only the observation next to the current observation. I sort them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a helper column containing the first two characters, provided that it is sorted as per the original question:

```
data temp;
input  customer_IN $ 1-8 initials $ 1-2;
cards;
ADJOHN. 
ADMARY.  
ADjerry.  
BWABBY.   
CFLUCY.   
CFLINDA.   
EFLAGNA.  
KTPAKAO.   
KTWANDA.    
;
run;

data want;
set temp;
by initials;
same_first_two_nearby = not(first.initials and last.initials);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you @user667489! It is a great help. I learn a lot from you.

Comment: I change a little. I use substr(customer_IN, 1,2) as your initials.;